# Counting member features in ArcGIS table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm working on Arcgis 10.3 and have a table as shown below.  I need to count each member of the Name field according (and not according) to Class Field.

[image: My_Table]

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what you need to do but it *sounds* like the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool will do what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to count distinct combinations of *Class* and *Name*, you can use the **Summary Statistics** tool. The key is to use the fields as your **Case** fields, like so:

[image]

This will generate an output table that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Frequency also works but needs an advanced license, summary statistics does (approximately) the same thing on any license level... it is a *very* handy tool.